# How many walks of length three between a node and itself in a two-node graph?

Tags: graph-theory

In Graph Theory there is the following theorem, which is from [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_chap05.pdf).

> **Theorem.** Let $G=(V,E)$ be an $n$-node graph with $V = \{v_1,v_2,\dotsc,v_n\}$ and let $A_G = \{a_{ij}\}$ denote the adjacency matrix for $G$. Let $a_{ij}^{(k)}$ denote the $(i,j)$-entry of the $k$<sup>th</sup> power of $A_G$. Then the number of walks of length $k$ between $v_i$ and $v_j$ is $a_{ij}^{(k)}$.

If I have a graph with two nodes, an edge connecting them, and a loop at each node, the, adjacency matrix is $2\times 2$ and has a one in every entry. If I square the matrix, the entries all become twos, and if I raise the matrix to the third power, the entries become eights.

In the context of the above theorem, the matrix to the third power contains the number of walks of length three between nodes in the graph. Entry $a_{11}$ of this matrix has value eight, which means there are eight walks of length three between $v_1$ and itself, but I can only count four of them:
$$
1\longrightarrow 1\longrightarrow 1\longrightarrow 1\\
1\longrightarrow 1\longrightarrow 2\longrightarrow 1\\
1\longrightarrow 2\longrightarrow 2\longrightarrow 1\\
1\longrightarrow 2\longrightarrow 1\longrightarrow 1
$$

What are the missing four walks?

Comment: With two nodes and an edge, I do not understand why you are assuming $a_{ii}=1$ also. Your matrix should be $a_{11}=a_{22}=0,a_{12}=a_{21}=1$.

Comment: @evianpring: In a simple graph (i.e., a graph without loop and parallel edges) the main diagonal of the adjacency matrix is always zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct, you just did the matrix multiplication wrong.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\\\end{pmatrix}^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}1+1&1+1\\1+1&1+1\\\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}2&2\\2&2\\\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\\\end{pmatrix}^3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\\\end{pmatrix}^2
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\\\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}2&2\\2&2\\\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\\\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}4&4\\4&4\\\end{pmatrix}
$$
So yeah, the four walks you found are accurate. You probably tried to calculate the third power of the matrix by squaring the matrix squared; this actually produces the matrix to the fourth power.